# Domain Masking one page

Tags: dns, masking

Good afternoon,

Is it possible to use domain masking for only one page on a site? For example we are using an LMS (Learning Management System) for one of our sites but still want to create landing pages externally on a site we have access to, as this will save us a ton of money, and then just mask the domain.

**EDIT**
Hey Wil, we actually don't need to show a page from the LMS on the other site. Maybe I should explain further.

Essentially we want to create a landing page that looks like it is hosted on the LMS site but really is on one of our other sites. This landing page wouldn't have any content from the LMS and would actually send users to an order page and that order page would send the users to the LMS eventually.

The LMS programmers charge $150 an hour so my boss doesn't want to use them for the little stuff that they will be doing all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Just configure your domain and create a landing page with a `<frame>` pointing to the LMS. This should work as long as the LMS doesn't refuse to run within a frame.

Comment: Hey Wil, we actually don't need to show a page from the LMS on the other site. Maybe I should explain further. Essentially we want to create a landing page that looks like it is hosted on the LMS site but really is on one of our other sites. This landing page wouldn't have any content from the LMS and would actually send users to an order page and that order page would send the users to the LMS eventually. Essentially the LMS programmers charge $150 an hour so my boss doesn't want to use them for the little stuff that they will be doing all the time.

Comment: I think I understand. You want people to browse to the same domain as the LMS, but instead of getting the LMS content they would see content that is hosted on your other site? If the LMS has a feature for you to create a page that redirects to another page, you can do so (but it sounds like they don't.)

Alternatively, put a proxy like nginx in front of the LMS and if the URL is /landing send the request to your own site, otherwise proxy it to the LMS.

There are variants to this, depending on what control over the LMS installation.